# Why does transform do side effects (println) only once in Structured Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Why does the `select` statement is printed every batch but the `hello world` only once?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(
  StructField("id", LongType, nullable = false) ::
  StructField("name", StringType, nullable = false) ::
  StructField("score", DoubleType, nullable = false) :: Nil)

val in: DataFrame = sparkSession.readStream
 .schema(schema)
 .format("csv")
 .option("header", false)
 .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
 .option("delimiter", ";")
 .load("s3://xxxxxxxx")

val input: DataFrame = in.select("*")
 .transform { ds =>
   println("hello world")  // <-- Why is this printed out once?
   ds
}

import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery
val query: StreamingQuery = input.writeStream
  .format("console")
  .start
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spark **2.1.0-SNAPSHOT** here (built today) but I believe it didn't change between 2.0 and now.

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT
      /_/

Branch master
Compiled by user jacek on 2016-09-30T07:08:39Z
Revision 1fad5596885aab8b32d2307c0edecbae50d5bd7a
Url https://github.com/apache/spark.git
Type --help for more information.
```

In Spark's [Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html), your streaming application is a *mere* trick to apply the same physical query plan to the input data sources.

Please note that the physical query plan is what makes your `Dataset` (and the more I'm with Spark SQL the more I see no difference between queries and datasets -- they're simply interchangeable these days).

When you describe a structured query (regardless of whether it is going to be a one-off or streaming query) it goes through 4 stages of parsing, analyzing, optimizing and finally producing physical plan. You can review it using `explain(extended = true)` method.

```
scala> input.explain(extended = true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@5c4f07c1,json,List(),Some(StructType(StructField(id,LongType,false), StructField(name,StringType,false), StructField(score,DoubleType,false))),List(),None,Map(path -> input-json)), FileSource[input-json], [id#15L, name#16, score#17]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
id: bigint, name: string, score: double
StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@5c4f07c1,json,List(),Some(StructType(StructField(id,LongType,false), StructField(name,StringType,false), StructField(score,DoubleType,false))),List(),None,Map(path -> input-json)), FileSource[input-json], [id#15L, name#16, score#17]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@5c4f07c1,json,List(),Some(StructType(StructField(id,LongType,false), StructField(name,StringType,false), StructField(score,DoubleType,false))),List(),None,Map(path -> input-json)), FileSource[input-json], [id#15L, name#16, score#17]

== Physical Plan ==
StreamingRelation FileSource[input-json], [id#15L, name#16, score#17]
```

The stages are lazy and executed only **once**.

Once you've got the physical plan, the stages won't be executed again. Your `Dataset` pipeline is already computed and the only missing piece is the data to flow through the pipe.

That's why you see "hello world" only once -- when the streaming query plan was "executed" to produce the physical plan. It was executed once and optimized for processing the source `Dataset` (and only the `Dataset` so any side effects were already triggered).

An interesting case. That's a lot for bringing it up here!